# How do I use an older version of a website's cookies on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I accidentally deleted a [banner](https://www.planetminecraft.com/banner/) on PlanetMinecraft and there's no default way to get it back.

It seems to have been saved via my computer's cookies instead of my account, so theoretically if I still had those I could find a way to override the current cookies with an older version. Is that how that works? How do I get that done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but if the data was in cookies that were deleted, then it might
be lost if you don't have the right backup.

The cookies are stored in an Sqlite database, so in database rows and not
in any text file that might be restored.
The database name is `Cookies` (of course). So only if you have a previous
backup of this file, you may restore it to reget your cookies.

The folder where this file resides is:

- Windows : `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`
- Mac OS X : `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies`
- Linux : `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/`